# Dropdownlist results in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm having some trouble getting the results of the drop-downs in a gridview, and haven't found any helpful articles for VB code. 
What I'm trying to do is build a site for tests. So far I have the gridview built w/the extra column for a drop-down list where the true/false answer will be selected. When the test is completed, there is a submit button. All is well except I need to be able to get the results of each drop-down list on post-back to a variable or array (each test contains 10 questions) so the results can be checked/graded. When the results are determined I would like to display a label in it's place and change the text value accordingly (correct or incorrect), so I'll need to be able to enumerate these as well (i.e. label1.text="Correct!", label2.text="Incorrect!", etc...).

Code so far.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" 
            BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1">
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" HeaderText="Question" 
            SortExpression="Question" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <% If Not IsPostBack Then%>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlAnswer" 
            DataTextField="torf" DataValueField="torf">
            </asp:DropDownList> 
            <%Else%>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <%End If%>    
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
</asp:GridView>
```

The preceding code loads 10 rows, 2 columns (column1:Question | column2-[DropDownLists]:Answer). I'm a freshman when it comes to development, so if you need additional info let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I handled it:
created a page level private variable to hold our list of correct/incorrect values
Private Answers as New List(Of Boolean) 'creates a strongly typed list of t/f values

in Page.Load

if IsPostBack then
 'iterate through each row
 for each gridRow As GridViewRow in GridView1.Rows
  'get the selected value for this answer
  Dim answer as string = CType(gridRow.FindControl("DropDownList1"),DropDownList).SelectedValue
  'add this answer to the list
  Answers.Add(IsCorrectAnswer(answer))
 next
end if

the IsCorrectAnswer function determines whether or not the answer given for this question is correct and returns a Boolean value.  You would need to write this function to suit your needs.

in Button1.Click handler

'rowCounter will act as an index to the answers
Dim rowCounter as Integer = 0
For Each gridRow as GridViewRow in GridView1.Rows
 'grid_RowDataBound handles the binding of single row
 grid_RowDataBound(gridRow, rowCounter)
 rowCounter+=1
Next

finally

Private Sub grid_RowDataBound(gridRow as GridViewRow, rowCounter as Integer)
    'make the dropdown invisible
    CType(gridRow.FindControl("DropDownList1"),DropDownList).Visible = False
    'because we'll be acting on two properties of the label, I shove it in a variable first for ease of access
    Dim label As Label = CType(gridRow.FindControl("Label1"),Label)
    'set the label to visible
    label.Visible = True
    'set the text
    label.Text = Iif(Answers(rowCounter),"Correct", "Incorrect")
End Sub

Someone probably has a cleaner solution than this, but I do know this works, at least as far as I understand the issue you are facing.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

What about binding the Visible attribute to `Page.IsPostBack` (note this is in C# since I'm not familiar with the syntax for VB.NET... I'm sure something similar would work):

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlAnswer" 
        DataTextField="torf" DataValueField="torf" Visible='<%# !Page.IsPostBack %/>></asp:DropDownList> 
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" Visible='<%# Page.IsPostBack %/></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the RowDataBound event of the gridview object.  It takes two parameters:
(byval sender as Object, byval e as GridViewRowEventArgs).  With it, you can set the value of the label in each row to 'Correct' or 'Incorrect' on the postback.

see the example at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx
for more information

as for getting the answers into a variable, here are a couple of options

1) check viewstate.  It has some overhead, so be cautious with it.
2) save the data to a Session object

Comment: thanks for the response, but I'm still stuck (and not for lack trying) 

again... I'm a noob to asp.net and vb.net. Could you provide an example on how to get the selected value of the first drop-down list which would be in column2/cell2 of the datagrid? I wasn't able to get what was needed from the article provided. Thanks in advance for any assistance.